# How to email orders to customer in php

Tags: php, mysql, email, shopping-cart

this is an edit and i have inserted below the updated code requested by nav.

Products Not Being Emailed To Customers Email. I have tried everything but cannot find the solution.

```
 <?
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("includes/functions.php");  

    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_price($pid);
            $date=date('Y/m/d');
            $user=$_SESSION['username'];
            $pname=get_product_name($pid);
            mysql_query("insert into `order` values ('','$pname','$q','$price','$date','$user')")

                or die(mysql_error());
                        }

        die('Thank You! your order has been placed! <br/> <a  href="login/order.php">Home</a>');
        /*session_unset(); */
        session_unset($_SESSION['cart']);

        session_destroy($_SESSION['cart']);

?>

<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","*******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('********', $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";//"CUSTOMERS ID" = the customer who you would like to email, their id from the DB

$q=mysql_query($sql,$con);

$r=mysql_fetch_array($q);

$messege = "Hi $user, <br/><br/> You Have Ordered The Following Items on $date :<br/> <br/>$pname <br/> $q <br/> $price  ";
$to= $r['email'];
$from = 'order@musicinc.com';
$subject="Your Order Has Been Placed";
mail($to,$subject,$messege,$from);

?>
```

i tried without the db query and inserted in my gmail but to no success at all.

***EDITED***

Comment: _Do not store passwords in plain text_.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Very common question, you should Google. Anyway http://php.net/mail

Comment: http://w3schools.com/php/ is good for newbies like yourself.

Comment: [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com) is even better

Comment: Depends if magic quotes is on or off. If magic quotes is on, turn it off and always escape input before putting it into mysql queries with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. You should always encrypt passwords with md5 as well.

Comment: @Dagon, Some interesting stuff there...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$messege = "Your email here....";
$to="the recipient (customer) here";
$from "your email address";
$subject="subject here";
mail($to,$subject,$messege,$from);
```

That should do the trick.

DB Query (You should of asked in your question....):

```
$con=mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);//make the appropriate changes to the variables..

$sel="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id='CUSTOMER ID'";//"CUSTOMERS ID" = the customer who you would like to email, their id from the DB

$q=mysql_query($sel,$con);

$r=mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

**EDIT**

```
function email_customer($to=""){
$messege = "Hi $user, <br/><br/> You Have Ordered The Following Items on $date :<br/> <br/>$pname <br/> $q <br/> $price  ";
$from = "order@musicinc.com";
$subject="Your Order Has Been Placed";
mail($to,$subject,$messege,"From: $from");
}; 

email_customer($r['email']);
```

The above is basically the same, just in a function.

Replace `$r['email'];` with your own email for testing: `email_customer("your@email.com");`

If that doesn't work, it's not the code..

Comment: hi nav, thanks for this! how do i actually query the customers email as on my website, once a user logs in he/she can place an order without entering his/her personal information. how do i retriveve the email from the database and stick it in the code you have shown me above?

Comment: thanks nav, but i am as a customer not still recieving any email. the bit where it says $message, i have added in the following: $messege = "Hi $user, <br/><br/> You Have Ordered The Following Items on $date :<br/> <br/>$pname <br/> $q <br/> $price  ";

Comment: test it without using the DB query to fetch the email, just use your email for testing: $to="youemail@email.com"; and let me know how that goes

Comment: I just tested the mail code myself and it works fine... are you on a local server? if so, try it on a remote. The mail function on your local may be disabled.

Comment: i have a similar piece of mail code on another site and it works fine on the same server. i dont think im putting the code in the right section of my code. do you think that is the casE? my own server allows the email function to work as i have done it before and 100% sure

Comment: nav i appreciate all your help. unfortunately its still not working. il have a in depth look at it later. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Zencart code (or possibly Oscommerce). These have inbuilt calls to send emails to customers and you will be best served by asking on the relevant support forum your the application even if you are trying to hack the code as it seems.

Comment: hi im not using zencart or oscommerce...iv followed a tutorial of a website which has no forums or help.

Comment: I strongly believe the tutorial has been built up around zencart code. Care to share a link to the tutorial site?

Comment: http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=25&title=Tutorial-Building-a-shopping-cart-in-PHP

Comment: Thanks. Looks like Nav is on this.

Comment: can i just say that the principle behind banning a user on stackoverflow is so stupid! how can other users give you negative reputations for a question they think is silly to be asked. after all this is a place where people come to help or ask questions if they are stuck with a problem! absoultly stupid i tell you! argh